# Why is pip not utilizing metadata of sdist package?

Tags: python, pip, sdist

When I use the default index URL for `pip`, it properly understands that certain version of the package is not compatible with the environment:

```
$ pip -v -i https://pypi.python.org/simple install setuptools
[...]
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8f/6b/0dcf95d95086ce459152e4c0ac306f2dbbcf984177a2b8b77b320ebfbf22/setuptools-53.1.0.tar.gz#sha256=8181c4625cd58fa7817761e0fa60f6fa3adc4c437f5c25377b1aefa861ca15a2 (from https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/) (requires-python:>=3.6)
```

This is the expected behavior (another suitable version of `setuptools` is selected). But when I install from own mirror, this wrong version is picked:

```
$ pip -v -i https://my.pypi.mirror install setuptools
[...]
    Found link https://my.pypi.mirror/%2Bf/818/1c4625cd58fa7/setuptools-53.1.0.tar.gz#sha256=8181c4625cd58fa7817761e0fa60f6fa3adc4c437f5c25377b1aefa861ca15a2 (from https://my.pypi.mirror/+simple/setuptools/), version: 53.1.0
Using version 53.1.0
```

The files are identical as their SHA256 sums show. What can be the reason that in the second case `pip` fails to correctly use the metadata of the package?

Comment: I do not really understand what you are trying to point at in your question. But my guess is that you are encountering the case of your mirror not providing any `requires-python` info. For example look at the source code of the page for https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/ and see how some of the `<a>` tags (links) have a `data-requires-python="&gt;=3.6"` attribute. This is probably the info that your mirror does not provide.

Comment: @sinoroc this seems to be exactly the reason! Looks like my local pip repository is not configured properly and does not provide `data-requires-python` attribute. I'd gladly accept this if you chose to make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably encountering the case of your mirror not providing any `requires-python` info. For example look at the source code of the page for https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools and see how some of the `<a>` tags (links) have a `data-requires-python="&gt;=3.6"` attribute. This is probably the info that your mirror does not provide and makes dependency resolution come to different choices.